# Can a Wizard ready a combat cantrip?

Tags: cantrips, pathfinder-2e, tactics

You can use Ready only for single actions:

> You prepare to use an action that will occur outside your turn. Choose a **single action** or free action you can use, and designate a trigger. Your turn then ends.

However, every cantrip you would *want* to Ready in combat takes 2 actions. Do you have to carry around a Sling just for Ready actions?

Comment: @MJdenis Please don't answer in comments, including link only. Please put that up as a full answer and use the video as additional explanation (or credit it for the elegance of explaination, as needed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 2 or 3 action activities cannot be Readied

You've properly quoted the [Ready](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=82) activity, and you are correct; most combat cantrips are two action activities, and thus cannot be Readied. Any one action spell should be Ready-able, however, such as a one action Magic Missile or one action Harm.

### Try Delay

While you cannot Ready the spells you are wanting to, you could simply [Delay](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=77) your turn. Yes, you have to wait for the enemy to finish their turn, but you can cast all sorts of spells in response.

### Quickened Casting (Homebrew Solution)

Your GM might allow [Quickened Casting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=199) to Ready a 2 action spell (which most of the combat cantrips are) - see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/182039/can-you-use-free-actions-as-part-of-a-ready-action).

### Variable Action Ready (Homebrew Solution)

I think this may be left over from the playtest, but you could allow for readying a 2 action activity by spending all 3 actions on Ready. This keeps the "tax" of Readying the same (1 action, 1 reaction). It is not what the rules allow for, though it may work for your needs.

Comment: Quickened does not work RAW because Ready is an action you take in between Quicken and the spell... although I'd probably allow it. I also support the Hombrew you suggest, although adding some experience/player reception besides my endorsement would be good too

Comment: @Ifusaso I personally don't use the homebrew solution in my game (other than one time when I thought it was the RAW on accident...). 

As for the Ready and Quickened Casting, I think it is a bit ambiguous; it might be worth another question. I could see a RAW argument for allowing it, considering the action sequence would seemingly be: Ready <X>X> {end turn} -> Quickened <F> -> Spell <X>. 

<F> meaning free action

Comment: I didn't think about whether you could use a Free action as part of a Ready... definitely another valid question.

Comment: [My take on it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/182039/28326) is that you are not able to do that