# Can you use free action(s) as part of a Ready Action?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, reactions

The most obvious example of this, which came up in regards to another question's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/182031/28326), is [Quickened Casting](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=199) Metamagic, but there may be other Free Actions that modify following actions or might otherwise be useful as part of Readying to act.

Are you able to perform one or more Free Actions as part of and/or when you perform your [Ready](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=82) activity activation?

Answer (score 5):

### You cannot ready a Free Action and an Action

Free Actions can be performed on your turn or when explicitly allowed by the Action (which is indicated by it having a Trigger)

> Free actions don’t require you to spend any of your three single actions or your reaction. **A free action might have a trigger like a reaction does. If so, you can use it just like a reaction**—even if it’s not your turn. However, you can use only one free action per trigger, so if you have multiple free actions with the same trigger, you have to decide which to use. **If a free action doesn’t have a trigger, you use it like a single action**, just without spending any of your actions for the turn.

The text on Ready specifies

> You prepare to use an action that will occur outside your turn. **Choose a single action or free action you can use, and designate a trigger.** Your turn then ends. If the trigger you designated occurs before the start of your next turn, you can use the chosen action as a reaction (provided you still meet the requirements to use it). You can’t Ready a free action that already has a trigger.

You can only prepare a single *or* Free action, not both. As such, casting any spell with more than 1 action cost as well as any other use of a Free action 'along with' a single action is disallowed.

Comment: Upon further examination, I agree that this holds true for Quickened Casting. Quickened Casting requires that your _next_ action be the spell, but you'd have to use the Ready action between the two. If it were worded differently (i.e. the next spell you cast takes one less action), I could see it working with Ready, since you are able to do the Quickened Casting action before ready. Or if Quickened Casting had the spell casting as a subordinate action.

Comment: Answer would be improved by including a quote on the rules on free actions that make it clear that you can't use them outside your turn under normal circumstances... and perhaps also the bit that makes it clear that readying an action ends your turn immediately (rather than permitting you to ready an action and then use a preparatory free action to boost it after readying but before you turn ends)

Comment: Heh.  Ironic... you can *almost* pull it off, except that the moment where you choose the action to ready is just barely *after* you've chosen the Ready action as your next action, and therefore "cast this spell as a single action" is no longer available to you.

Comment: Yeah there are a number of things that line up to make it explicitly disallowed. Not sure what the reasoning was. Yeah I'll add details about what a Free action is/when you can use it. Actually, that reminds me of another question I thought of but forgot to post...